# How to debug long running python scripts or services remotely?

Tags: python, debugging, uwsgi, paster

Pretty much what the title says, I would like to be able to connect to a python process running under paster or uwsgi and utilize pdb functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Using [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/), you can attach to a running process like this:

1. Insert

   ```
   import rpdb2; rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger('mypassword')
   ```

   inside your script.
2. Launch your script (through paster or uwsgi) as usual.
3. Run winpdb
4. Click File>Attach
5. Type in password (e.g. "mypassword"), select the process.
6. To detach, click File>Detach. The script will continue to run, and can be attached to again later.