# How to print the most recent last call on linux without exiting the program

Tags: python, linux, call

When I execute a python script on linux and interrupt the process, it gives me the " most recent call last":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clustermptest.py", line 38, in <module>
    if sequences[i][x:x+3]==CAI[cailength][1]:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Is there a way to see what the most recent call last is ie the line it is currently processing while the script is still running/without stopping the script?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) to [attach to your running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082093/how-to-debug-long-running-python-scripts-or-services-remotely/7082688#7082688) and allow you to break, inspect, and resume it at various points.

---

Or, you could define a signal handler, although this may not be a completely robust solution especially if you are using threads:

```
import signal
import traceback

def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
    # ctrl-c generates SIGINT
    traceback.print_stack()
    print('-'*80)

def foo():
    total = 0
    for i in range(10**8):
        total += i
    return total

if __name__=='__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
    print(foo())
```

---

Running `test.py`, and pressing `C-c` at various moments yields:

```
  C-c C-c  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(foo())
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 14, in foo
    for i in range(10**8):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 9, in sigint_handler
    traceback.print_stack()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  C-c C-c  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(foo())
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 15, in foo
    total += i
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 9, in sigint_handler
    traceback.print_stack()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4999999950000000
```

References:

1. [The signal module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) (be sure to read the caveats)
2. [The traceback module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)
3. [Doug Hellman's Python Module of the Week tutorial on using
   signal](http://pymotw.com/2/signal/)